# Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. Embedded Kafka Spring test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm trying to see if a method from Service class is invoked when the consumer consumes a message from Kafka topic but i'm getting the error that there is no zero interactions with the Mock. When the test is running it consumes the message and I can see on terminal that the service method is actually invoked (i tried with prints), but it is not passing the test.

My Consumer class:

```
@Component
public class Consumer {
  
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic")
    public void consume(String message) { 
        service.add();
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" })
class ConsumerTest {

  @Mock( lenient = true)
  private Service service;

  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

  @InjectMocks
  private Consumer consumer;

  @Test
  public void givenEmbeddedKafkaBroker_whenExistsTemperatureMessageInTopic_thenMessageReceivedByConsumerAndServiceInvoked() 
    throws Exception {

      String message = "Hello";

      kafkaTemplate.send("topic", message);

      Mockito.verify(service, times(1)).add();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your consumer class has a service field that you never pass the mocked service instance to it during the test

Comment: how i need to pass it?

Comment: Rather than using `InjectMocks`, create a Constructor in your Consumer class that accepts a Service

Comment: You also need to actually use the Consumer in your tests

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Don't use @Mock with @SpringBootTest. Use @MockBean instead.

The components you created in your test don't take part in the message processing:

- consumer
- service

This stems from the fact that you used @SpringBootTest annotation, which brings up entire application context. This means that Spring creates all services itself, and happily ignores the ones created in the test.

- To replace a bean from the test, use @MockBean
- To inject a bean created by Spring to your test, use @Autowired

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue, and solved by using the Spybean instead of the MockBean, maybe you can have a try to use the SpyBean, your code will be something like this:

```
class ConsumerTest {

@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

@SpyBean
private Consumer consumer;
```